# How to modify Map's output style?

Tags: java, dictionary, pretty-print

I have a method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long> var = Files.walk(Paths.get("text"), number)
                .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path))
                    .map(Path::getFileName)
                    .map(Object::toString)
                    .filter(fileName -> fileName.contains("."))
                    .map(fileName -> fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                    extension -> extension,
                                    Collectors.counting()
                            )
                    );
        System.out.println(var);
}
```

As we know, output will be like:

```
{text=1, text=2}
```

Is it possible to change the output to:

```
text = 1
text = 2
```

I want to have some more freedom, e. g. remove brackets and commas, add new lines after number etc.

Comment: You probably want to create a custom `Map` class that handles this form of printing in it's `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the results of the map, and just print them out:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : var.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Then if you want more control, you can just modify how the line gets printed, since you have the raw key and value objects.

Comment: This is a lot better option than trying to fiddle with the behavior of the class itself, which is likely to be fragile and limit flexibility.

Comment: @chrylis Creating subclasses to do new things is the whole idea behind Object Oriented design concepts. If you wanted to change the `toString` behavior then you subclass and override `toString`. It has no other effect on the parent class's functionality or the code in place. Given that `Map` is an interface, there would be no code change necessary. Doing it like this answer suggests, free form violates OO design practices by putting logic belonging to the `Map` outside of the class representing the `Map`.

Comment: @BrandonBuck You will learn as you get experience. This *might* theoretically be a suitable case for composition, but certainly not inheritance, as the desired behavior is not attached to any particular **implementation** of `Map`. This is much more akin to writing a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: @chrylis I did think about suggesting something along those lines. That would be a more ideal solution in a professional environment. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

What about something as simple as:

```
map.toString().replace(", ", "\n");
```

Comment: This is partial, you'd get a string like: `"{text=1\ntext=2}"`

Comment: Yes, but I've illustrated the principle.